# Bash - How to check if all array values are greater than specific number

Tags: bash, shell

How to check if all array values are greater than specific number in bash

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather overly engineered answer, meant to work like functional methods in other languages:

```sh
gt() { (( $1 > $2 )); }

all() {
  local -n _ary=$1
  local func=$2
  shift 2
  for elem in "${_ary[@]}"; do
    "$func" "$elem" "$@" || return 1
  done
}

array=(5 6 7 8 9 10)

if all array gt 4;  then echo true; else echo false; fi   # true
if all array gt 40; then echo true; else echo false; fi   # false
```

This uses a nameref thus requires bash version 4.3+

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
number=42
arr=(56 120 74 52 12)

all_greater=1
for element in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    if (( element <= number )) ; then
        all_greater=0
    fi
done
if (( all_greater )) ; then
    echo All values are greater.
else
    echo Some values aren\'t greater.
fi
```